# What's the purpose of IAuthenticationFilter.OnAuthenticationChallenge()

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a custom [IAuthenticationFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filters.iauthenticationfilter%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) implementation registered in `RegisterGlobalFilters()`. In my project I'm witnessing the following call sequence:

1. IAuthenticationFilter.OnAuthentication
2. authorization (if any)
3. controller action
4. IAuthenticationFilter.OnAuthenticationChallenge

Why does it happen *after* controller action? From [this blog post](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=957) I read

> The key thing to remember is that `OnAuthenticationChallenge` does not
>   necessarily run before every other Action Filter. It can run at
>   various stages.

How can it be useful if we can't tell when exactly it is called?

Comment: The blog post you mention, also says: "OnAuthenticationChallenge method runs after the OnAuthentication method. You can use OnAuthenticationChallenge method to perform additional tasks on the request." So basicly, if you want to modify your Action result, you may implement it on "OnAuthenticationChallenge" method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Source](http://books.google.pt/books?id=ZqZ4AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA495&lpg=PA495&dq=implementing%20OnAuthenticationChallenge%20asp%20net&source=bl&ots=vtnWBZ5xoR&sig=rgsbkuJIYhsf-rGlyArApS-Jukk&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ei=AGEYU4jbIsX9ygPvq4GoDg&ved=0CE0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=implementing%20OnAuthenticationChallenge%20asp%20net&f=false)

"The OnAuthenticationChallange method is called by the MVC Framework whenever a request has failed the authentication or authorization policies for an action method. The [OnAuthenticationChallenge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onauthenticationchallenge%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method is passed an [AuthenticationChallengeContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filters.authenticationchallengecontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) object, which is derived from the ControllerContext class"

So, a practical example would be:

1 - You set your custom authorize filter

2 - users fails on authorizing method

3 - [OnAuthenticationChallenge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onauthenticationchallenge%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method is called.

Comment: OnAuthenticationChallenge is called to do what?

Comment: @BigTundra - for example to redirect a user to the login page